# LEFT JOIN not showing all rows for table on the left

Tags: mysql, join

Consider this query:

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT( ssh_logs.id ) AS ssh_count FROM servers s 
LEFT JOIN logs ssh_logs ON s.ip_address = ssh_logs.server_ip
```

I am under the impression the `LEFT JOIN` shows all rows on the left table, regardless of whether there's a match for the `ON` condition.

```
SELECT s.* FROM servers s
```

Returns 12 entries, while the first query returns only 1 where the ip addresses match.

So how do I get the first query to display all the rows in servers table alongwith the joined table data?

Comment: i think if you remove COUNT( ssh_logs.id ) you will get all rows.

Comment: @Sabeen, yep but that will defeat the purpose of the query.

Comment: @Johan yeah but by comparison the 2 queries shouldn't be seen to return the same number of rows. Just trying to point the OP to debug by elimination.

Comment: @Sabeen, if servers.ip_address is a unique field, a query with `group by servers.ip_address` will return 12 rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The aggregate function count() collapses all rows into one.
Do a `group by` to see the count per ip-address.

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(ssh_logs.id) AS ssh_count FROM servers s  
LEFT JOIN logs ssh_logs ON s.ip_address = ssh_logs.server_ip 
GROUP BY s.ip_address
```

This will work best if servers.ip_address is an unique field for servers (primary key or unique index).
If servers has duplicate ip_addresses than this query will group those ip_addresses together and hide data that should be hidden.

However given the fact that these are servers it is logical to assume ip_address is unique.